# combine two node forms .. is that possible?

Tags: forms, drupal-6, cck

I'm using drupal 6 and I got a node_form for content type 1, I want to alter the other content type node form inside the first one, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add values from 1st form to 2nd form you can use hook_nodeapi() to altering 2nd content types node.

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL){
  switch($op){
    case 'presave':
      if($node->type == MY_NODE_TYPE){
        // $other_node = node_load($other_nid);
        // or
        // $other_node = new stdClass();
        // $other_node->title = ...
        // ...
        // some code to altering other node
        // $other_node = node_submit($other_node);
        // node_save($other_node);
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah but what about the form ? how do i alter the fields and titles from that form

Comment: what do you want to do, update existant node or create new node of other type?

Comment: just alter the fields from content type 1 to other content type in formapi way : $form[contenttypefiled1]=all values, min/max, prefix suffix  , class and attribues etc

Comment: can you retrieve NID of node of other type ?